# TypeScript: assign readonly to non-readonly. Is this a bug?

Tags: typescript

I found something which seems to be an obvious bug in TS 4.4, but I wanted to ask here first, just in case I missed something obviuos.

```js
const x = {
  a: 42
} as const

interface A {
  a: number;
}

const y: A = x; // this should raise an error, but doesn't

y.a = 24;

const b = x.a;
//    ^?
// b is incorrectly inferred to be 42
```

If this is the intended behavior, is there any actual reason to use `Readonly`? I prefer to be honest about my types.

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=15&ssc=37&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA3gKBpmBDAXDAFgCY0BfHCGUSKNNASzCgFMAnAM22GZgEFUMWPDDABXALYAjNgG4ydatBgBPfP2RwZMAPTaYUABb1KEAyFEAbACYxW2Yz2xgYbViFYAaGJNGwrIZggwAHJaNGUAOmwkGCICOTRFWEkYuCi5XSwYAD0AfjRMlOMYRlBWVmZgKAtlErB2NmYbKBBvHmI6OiA), just in case someone'd like to play with this.